# (MON_OBJ_METRICS) in db2

Tags: db2

I am very much new to db2. My requirement is I just want to remove tracking system on a user table. I mean  tracking of all kind of DML operations on a particular table. I read some thing from the google, according to my understanding this can be done by this parameter in (MON_OBJ_METRICS) parameter at db level.does my understanding is worth ?
How can i disable this parameter ? If i disable this parameter at db level, does all the tables under this particular database are quit from tracking ?

On sql server we can do this by set_change_tracking parameter. I am looking for same functionality in db2luw.
Kindly help me out & please excuse me , as i m a kid in db2

Answer (score 1):

`MON_OBJ_METRICS` (and `DFT_MON_TABLE`, from your other post) are used for performance monitoring only.  The keep track of the *number* of rows read, inserted, deleted and updated (among other things), but do *not* track actual data changes.

Change tracking in MS SQL Server is used for data capture to feed replication processes, not monitoring.

In DB2 you can set the `DATA CAPTURE` table parameter to `NONE`, but be aware that this is its default value.  You can check the current value for a table with the following query:

```
SELECT datacapture
  FROM syscat.tables
 WHERE tabschema = <schema>
   AND tabname   = <tablename>
```

You can modify the setting using:

```
ALTER TABLE <schema>.<tablename> DATA CAPTURE NONE
```

Comment: Superb Ian U clarified me what I am looking for all these days. Its a very good thing & Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `DATA CAPTURE` option that Ian described, DB2 v10.1 and newer can also track changes made to tables that are enabled for system-period temporal versioning. System-period versioning is not enabled by default, but if it is, every DML change to the table is automatically captured into a designated history table with the same column layout. Unlike SQL Server's retention policy for tracking changes, the DBA is responsible for pruning old row versions out of DB2 temporal history tables.

The SYSCAT.TABLES view will reveal which tables are enabled for system-period versioning:

`SELECT tabschema, tabname FROM syscat.tables 
 WHERE temporaltype IN ( 'B', 'S' )`

The following statement will disable whichever temporal features are enabled ( system-period, business-period, or both):

`ALTER TABLE <schema>.<tablename> DROP VERSIONING`